# Django Gunicorn - gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I had a Django/Gunicorn app running just fine, but after a code update it stopped working due to this gunicorn error. I don't think anything has changed regarding that setup, so I am at a loss as to why it won't work now.

/etc/systemd/system/triform.service

```
[Unit]
Description=triform daemon
Requires=triform.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/triform/django
ExecStart=/home/triform/django/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          triform.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/triform.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=triform socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/triform.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/home/triform/django/triform/wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'triform.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

in /home/triform/django/triform/settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'triform.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with the service syntax. Is this the correct syntax? `triform.wsgi:application`. Shouldn't that be `triform.wsgi.application`?

Comment: The colon appears to be the correct syntax. And this works on a second site that is running on the same server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn

Comment: Then I'm at a loss as well. Is there more error output from Gunicorn?

Comment: Just the error in the title. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Weird. It's looking for a variable in the module `triform`, while it should look inside the module `triform.wsgi`. I have no clue why, sorry!

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: what is your output of `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn` ? In some cases, you might get error-source from there

Answer (score 0):

I had to update gunicorn to the latest version, and also my Dockerfile to Python 3.9. If you are running this outside of Docker you can just upgrade. Make sure that you update old dependencies.

Once I upgraded gunicorn, and python the issue resolved.